# Inverse Function (and WolframAlpha gives different Result)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, wolfram-alpha

I wanted to calculate the inverse function of 
$$
 f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x-1}
$$
Quite simple I thought, put
$$
 y = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{2x-1}{x(x-1)}
$$
rearrange and solve
$$
 y(x(x-1)) - 2x + 1 = 0
$$
which give the quadratic equation
$$
 yx^2 - (y + 2)x + 1 = 0
$$
Using the [Solution Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) we got
$$
 x = \frac{(y+2) \pm \sqrt{y^2+4}}{2y}
$$
So the inverse function is
$$
 f^{-1}(x) = \frac{(x+2) \pm \sqrt{x^2+4}}{2x}
$$
Just to confirm I put in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverseFunction%281/x%20%2b%201/%28x-1%29%29) and it gives me
$$
 \frac{-x-2}{2x} \pm \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2x}
$$
(just click on the link to start WolframAlpha with this parameter), which
is different up to a sign in the first summand, can not see an error, do you (or is WolframAlpha wrong...)?

*EDIT*: If the link is not working for you:

[image]

Comment: WolframAlpha? Wrong? Blasphemy!

Comment: Do y9ou know a way to check whether the answer is wrong?  (Other than just re-computing it, of course.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your answer! Actually Wolfram's answer is wrong! Just check it by $x=3/2$ in wolfram's inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in the solution formula. You have $(y+2)^2 - 4\cdot y\cdot 1 = y^2+4 \neq (y+2)(y-2)$. It would be $y^2-4 = (y+2)(y-2)$.

Comment: yes, that was wrong! but this is not the issue, still the sign in the first summand is different: $-x-2$ vs. $(x+2)$! but thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

this function is not a one by one function , so that have not inverse .
but in some interval is 1-1 function so may have inverse[image]

Comment: maybe therefore it gives a wrong solution. btw do you know a way to specify the domain in InverseFunction for WolframAlpha?

Comment: can you calculate inverse of y=X^2 in all x ?

Comment: but you can restrict x to have inverse function . like this y=x^2 over x<0 or x>=2 or something like that

Comment: I suggest that ,apply restricted area of x in it. like x>1 and get the answer from wolfram

Comment: how to input that?

Comment: I do not know how to input on wolfram !

Comment: But if you restrict x domain ,I can solve it by hand ,and take a picture and paste here.

Comment: what you mean by that, isn't it solved in my post by hand?

Comment: choose a point in x>1 like x=2 ,so (2, f(2)) is on function ,therefore (f(2),2) must be on inverse function ,suppose x>1 from begin and choose the sign of + ,- for the solution that you write it above .

Comment: ah, okay you mean incorporating the cases which I did not in my solution, yes that would be necessary for a nice solution